# Find 4-dimensional vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a question about linear algebra: $\DeclareMathOperator{\Ker}{Ker}\DeclareMathOperator{\Im}{Im}$

**Let** $V,W$ be $\mathbb{C}$-vector spaces, $S: V \rightarrow W$, $T: V \rightarrow W$ be linear functions. We assume:

- $\dim V= \dim W =5$
- $\Ker(S)\cap \Ker(T) = \{0\}$
- $\forall(a,b)\in \mathbb{C}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$, $\dim\bigl(\Im(aS+bT)\bigr)=3$

Prove that: $\exists K\subset W$ is a vector space such that: 
$$\dim K = 4,\enspace\Im(S),\Im(T)\subset K. $$

$\textbf{Some steps}$: From the third assumption, we obtain $\dim\bigl(\Im(S)\bigr) = \dim\bigl(\Im(T)\bigr) = 3$. By Rank-nullity theorem, we know that: $$\dim \Ker(S)+\dim \Im(S)= \dim V$$
$$\Rightarrow \dim \Ker(S) = \dim V - \dim \bigl(\Im(S)\bigr)=5-3=2$$
Similarly, $$\dim \Ker(T) =2$$
Let $\{a_1,a_2\}$ be a basis of $\Ker(S)$, $\{a_3,a_4\}$ be a basis of $\Ker(T)$. By the second assumption, $\{a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4\}$ is a linearly  independent set. If we write $a_1=a_1+0$, $a_1$ can be in $\Ker(S)+\Ker(T)$. Hence, $$\{a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4\}\subset \Ker(S)+\Ker(T)$$
We also know from the second assumption that $$\dim\bigl(\Ker(S)+\Ker(T)\bigr)=\dim\bigl(\Ker(S)\bigr)+\dim\bigl(\Ker(T)\bigr)=2+2=4$$
Thus, $\{a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4\}$ is a basis of $\Ker(S)+\Ker(T)$.

I expect the vector space $K$ will relate to $\Ker(S)+\Ker(T)$ somehow. 
Could you help me?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Why does the third assumption imply that dimensions of the images are $3$?

Comment: I am sorry. My mistake. It should be equal to three.